# What visual state adaptive trigger approach should i use to run uwp app across multiple devices and resolutions?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Developing a uwp app and the requirement for the app is to  support across multiple devices and different resolutions (Tablets, laptops and Desktops).  ***The app main requirement mentions all the controls in the app should be horizontally aligned with no compromise***  And the alignment should not get changed based on devices and resolutions and orientation  and i am using VisualState.StateTriggers to achieve the  desired output

[image: Sample Design of the single page]

- 

Should I use  MinWindowHeight or  MinWindowWidth. I used MinWindowHeight  because all my controls are horizontally aligned.
When i use MinWindowHeight application is ok in landscape device orientation but not ok in portrait device orientation.
What is the best approach to meet the requirement.

```
    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
     <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="0" />
     </VisualState.StateTriggers>
      <VisualState.Setters>
          <Setter Target="COMMANDBAR.HEIGHT" Value="10" />
           <Setter Target="DATAGRID.HEIGHT" Value="10" />
           <Setter Target="ACTIONBUTTONS.HEIGHT" Value="10" />
           <Setter Target="PANEL1.HEIGHT" Value="10" />
           <Setter Target="TAB.HEIGHT" Value="10" />
     </VisualState.Setters>
    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
      <VisualState.StateTriggers>
           <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="650" />
 </VisualState.StateTriggers>
 <VisualState.Setters>
<Setter Target="COMMANDBAR.HEIGHT" Value="30" />
<Setter Target="DATAGRID.HEIGHT" Value="30" />
  <Setter Target="ACTIONBUTTONS.HEIGHT" Value="30" />
<Setter Target="PANEL1.HEIGHT" Value="30" />
 <Setter Target="TAB.HEIGHT" Value="30" />
</VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: What does "but not ok in portrait device orientation" mean? Can you provide more details  about this unexpected behavior?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, on landscape orientation the application real estate is maximumly used but on portrait orientation more real estate is left empty. for example on 1366*768 resolution landscape orientation for 768 height space is maximum used but same in portrait  mode more space is left empty.

Comment: When the device is in portrait mode, do you mean you want the application fill the whole window(e.g. the height on landscape orientation is 768 and on portrait orientation will be 1366)? Maybe you could detect the current rotation status of the device and then re-layout it.

Comment: Yes, want the application to use maximum space in any device orientation. Is the approach of visual state adaptive triggers on  MinWindowHeight is it the right way to do.

Comment: Based on your description, do you want to display the application in full screen?

Comment: Yes in Fullscreen i should dsplay.

Comment: You could use ApplicationView.TryEnterFullScreenMode() method to place the app in full-screen mode. In addition, it is feasible to use visual state adaptive triggers on MinWindowHeight. When I tested it, it could display well on both landscape and  portrait orientation.